# m_msgCur in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I'm currently transferring old source code to Visual Studio 2019.

The original code is from VC++6 or older.

In Windows MFC, there is a class called `CWinThread`, and according to the old source code, `m_msgCur` exists in the class. However, in VS2019, it says that `m_msgCur` does not exist. Then I found that `m_msgCur` existed long ago (https://github.com/dblock/msiext/blob/master/externals/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/inc/mfc42/afxwin.h, MFC 4.2) and it is deleted in VS2019. MSG `m_msgCur` contains current message of the thread, but is there any alternative variable in VS2019?

```
// message pump for Run
MSG m_msgCur;                   // current message
```

**Edited:**

Project link: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/halflife/tree/master/utils/serverctrl

Class `CServerCtrlDlg` (inherited from `CDialog`) is declared in `ServerCtrlDlg.h`. `ServerCtrlDlg.cpp` contains how it works. `ServerCtrlClg.cpp` includes `<afxpriv.h>`, and `<afxpriv.h>` contains `afxwin.h`, which has `CWinThread`.

**Part of ServerCtrlDlg that uses m_msgCur**

```
int CServerCtrlDlg::RunModalLoop(DWORD dwFlags)
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); // window must be created
    ASSERT(!(m_nFlags & WF_MODALLOOP)); // window must not already be in modal state

    // for tracking the idle time state
    BOOL bIdle = TRUE;
    LONG lIdleCount = 0;
    BOOL bShowIdle = (dwFlags & MLF_SHOWONIDLE) && !(GetStyle() & WS_VISIBLE);
    HWND hWndParent = ::GetParent(m_hWnd);
    m_nFlags |= (WF_MODALLOOP|WF_CONTINUEMODAL);
    MSG* pMsg = &AfxGetThread()->m_msgCur;

    // acquire and dispatch messages until the modal state is done
    for (;;)
    {
        ASSERT(ContinueModal());

        int iRet = RMLPreIdle();

        if (iRet < 0)
            goto ExitModal;
        else if (iRet > 0)
            continue;

        // phase1: check to see if we can do idle work
        while (bIdle &&
            !::PeekMessage(pMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            ASSERT(ContinueModal());

            // show the dialog when the message queue goes idle
            if (bShowIdle)
            {
                ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                UpdateWindow();
                bShowIdle = FALSE;
            }

            // call OnIdle while in bIdle state
            if (!(dwFlags & MLF_NOIDLEMSG) && hWndParent != NULL && lIdleCount == 0)
            {
                // send WM_ENTERIDLE to the parent
                ::SendMessage(hWndParent, WM_ENTERIDLE, MSGF_DIALOGBOX, (LPARAM)m_hWnd);
            }
            if ((dwFlags & MLF_NOKICKIDLE) ||
                !SendMessage(WM_KICKIDLE, MSGF_DIALOGBOX, lIdleCount++))
            {
                // stop idle processing next time
                bIdle = FALSE;
            }
        }

        // phase2: pump messages while available
        do
        {
            BOOL ShouldPump = TRUE;

            ASSERT(ContinueModal());

            // See if we are requiring messages to be in queue?
            if ( m_bOnlyPumpIfMessageInQueue )
            {
                // If there isn't a message, don't turn over control to PumpMessage
                //  since it will block
                if ( !::PeekMessage( pMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE ) )
                {
                    ShouldPump = FALSE;
                }
            }

            // pump message, but quit on WM_QUIT
            if ( ShouldPump )
            {
                if (!AfxGetThread()->PumpMessage())
                {
                    AfxPostQuitMessage(0);
                    return -1;
                }

                // show the window when certain special messages rec'd
                if (bShowIdle &&
                    (pMsg->message == 0x118 || pMsg->message == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
                {
                    ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
                    UpdateWindow();
                    bShowIdle = FALSE;
                }

                if (!ContinueModal())
                    goto ExitModal;

                // reset "no idle" state after pumping "normal" message
                if (AfxGetThread()->IsIdleMessage(pMsg))
                {
                    bIdle = TRUE;
                    lIdleCount = 0;
                }
            }

        } while (::PeekMessage(pMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE));
    }
ExitModal:
    m_nFlags &= ~(WF_MODALLOOP|WF_CONTINUEMODAL);
    return m_nModalResult;
}
```

Comment: MFC allows you to hook into its message processing code (e.g. [ProcessMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinthread-class#processmessagefilter)). Depending on when and why you need to access the message that's currently being handled, there are several ways to get it. An answer will depend on this information, so you'll need to include it in your question.

Comment: @IInspectable I updated my question and added the source link and the some of the codes.

Comment: The code shown doesn't seem to rely on `m_msgCur` being populated elsewhere - it just uses it as a local variable. Make it `MSG msg = {0}; MSG* pMsg = &msg;` and see if the code still works.

Comment: This you see this? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/58f762df-8f38-4e07-843e-858b32d59294/mmsgcur-undeclared-conversion-problem-from-vc-60-to-net-c?forum=vcgeneral `AfxGetThreadState()->m_msgCur.wParam;`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Problem with that is it would break `AfxGetCurrentMessage` which some MFC code relies on, for example to fetch the exit code from `PostQuitMessage`. Disclaimer: this is not meant as an endorsement of MFC design, just a statement of fact ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is to replace:

```
    MSG* pMsg = &AfxGetThread()->m_msgCur;  // vc++ 6
```

with:

```
    MSG *pMsg = AfxGetCurrentMessage();     // vc++ 2019
```

A better answer, however, is that if you *must* hack `CWnd::RunModalLoop` then you should do it right, and update `CServerCtrlDlg::RunModalLoop` to base it on the current `CWnd::RunModalLoop` code from VC++ 2019, instead of the old code borrowed from VC++ 6.

Comparing `CServerCtrlDlg::RunModalLoop` to the `CWnd::RunModalLoop` implementation in VC++ 6 from `mfc\src\wincore.cpp` shows the following lines marked with `//++` as having been added.

```
int CServerCtrlDlg::RunModalLoop(DWORD dwFlags)
{
//...
    // acquire and dispatch messages until the modal state is done
    for (;;)
    {
        ASSERT(ContinueModal());

        int iRet = RMLPreIdle();                                                    //++
                                                                                    //++
        if (iRet < 0)                                                               //++
            goto ExitModal;                                                         //++
        else if (iRet > 0)                                                          //++
            continue;                                                               //++

        // phase1: check to see if we can do idle work
        while (bIdle &&
            !::PeekMessage(pMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE))
        {
            ASSERT(ContinueModal());
//...
//...
        // phase2: pump messages while available
        do
        {
            ASSERT(ContinueModal());

            BOOL ShouldPump = TRUE;                                                 //++
                                                                                    //++
            // See if we are requiring messages to be in queue?                     //++
            if ( m_bOnlyPumpIfMessageInQueue )                                      //++
            {                                                                       //++
                // If there isn't a message, don't turn over control to PumpMessage //++
                //  since it will block                                             //++
                if ( !::PeekMessage( pMsg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_NOREMOVE ) )        //++
                {                                                                   //++
                    ShouldPump = FALSE;                                             //++
                }                                                                   //++
            }                                                                       //++

            if ( ShouldPump )                                                       //++
            {
                /* mfc code executed conditionally */
            }
//...
}
```

`CServerCtrlDlg::RunModalLoop` should be updated to use the VC++ 2019 `CWnd::RunModalLoop` code, instead, then those `//++` lines merged into it. The MFC changes in `CWnd::RunModalLoop` are small enough between the two versions that merging is straightforward.